# Finding duplicate entries in Spring Boot MongoDB?

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot

I'm new to Spring Boot and I've been trying to find out how you go about finding duplicates in MongoDB and reporting it.

For example each entry has an _id for database use, an entry name, and a barcode. All three of these need to be unique identifiers which can be searched.

For example. A user has created 100 entries a while back and for some reason has forgotten they've created a "Jaffa" entry with a barcode of 255.

Despite the app having a search function, the user neglects using it for what ever reason and they cannot find it the old fashioned way so tries to create a new "Jaffa" entry with the same barcode as above.

How do I get my app to look through the DB and report if the entry already exists or create otherwise either using the name or the barcode?

Thanks

Comment: Wouldn't that be far more suitable for a RDBMS than a NoSQL database? A unique constraint will prevent duplicates in either case though.

Answer (score 0):

You can use update with upsert option set to true. When you create a newEntry with whatever name, if it exists then it will update the existing entry data and if it doesn't exist then it creates a new document when no document matches the query criteria.
Here it is db.collection.update(query, update, options). 
For ex:
`db.collection.update({entryName: newEntry}, {$set: {entryName: newEntry: barcode: newBarCode}}, {upsert : true})`